# Comparing two List values in JSTL tag

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, jstl

I'm comparing two different values each from different list using JSTL tag, but I keep getting the error. I tried to change the brackets associated with it, but none worked. I searched for comparing two list values in JSTL, but none helps me.

```
<c:forEach items="${commentsList}" var="commentsList">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${ ${commentsList.user.id} == '${blog.user.id}' }">
            <li>
                <div class="timeline-panel" style="float:right">
                    <div class="timeline-heading" align="left">
                        <b>${commentsList.user.firstName}&nbsp;${commentsList.user.lastName}</b>
                    </div><hr>
                    <div class="timeline-body" style="float: right;">
                        <p>${commentsList.comment}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </li>
       </c:when>                            
       <c:otherwise>
           <li class="timeline-inverted">
                <div class="timeline-panel">                                         
                    <b>${commentsList.user.firstName}&nbsp;${commentsList.user.lastName}</b><hr>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>${commentsList.comment}</p>                                                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </c:otherwise>                              
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Error is

```
"${ ${commentsList.user.id} == '${blog.user.id}' }" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: ${ ${commentsList.user.id} == '${blog.user.id}' }
```

I've not compared two list values before, btw I can compare two list values in jstl right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an extra `$`.
try this:

```
<c:when test="${ commentsList.user.id eq blog.user.id}">
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. It seems $ infront will eliminate the need of $ inside {}.

Answer (score 1):

You should change to

```
<c:when test="${commentsList.user.id eq blog.user.id}">
```